# react native - react-native-maps initialRegion not work

Tags: javascript, ios, google-maps, react-native, react-native-maps

I integrated Google Map for iOS device using `react-native-maps`. I have a problem that `initialRegion` does not work after I re-render the map.

My application contain only 2 component: `MapView` from `react-native-maps` and a `Button`. Click on the button to show or hide the map.

Here is my code:

```
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
            {this.renderMap()}
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={this.onButtonPress.bind(this)}
                style={styles.showMapButtonContainer}>
                <Text style={styles.showMapButtonText}>Show and Hide Map</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
    );
}

renderMap() {
    if (this.state.showMap) {
        return (
            <MapView
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                style={styles.map}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: 37.78825,
                    longitude: -122.4324,
                    latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                    longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                }}
                cacheEnabled={true}
                onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChangeComplete.bind(this)}
            >
            </MapView>
        );
    } else {
        return <View style={styles.map}/>;
    }
}

onButtonPress() {
    this.setState({
        showMap: !this.state.showMap,
    })
}

onRegionChangeComplete(region) {
    console.log("new region", region)
}
```

First time load map, everything work perfectly. However, when I hide the map and show it again by clicking on the button it render a random region:

```
{ 
  longitude: 0,
  latitudeDelta: 0.0004935264587338631,
  latitude: 0,
  longitudeDelta: 0.00027760863304138184 
}
```

I tried `cacheEnabled` equal `true` and `false` but no help. Please let me know if you have any suggestion. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When you First time load the page it will call `initialRegion` and when you hide show the map it will not again call `initialRegion` function because map is already loaded before so you need to call function on hide/show method and set `initialRegion` by the following method

```
this.map.setNativeProps({ region });
```

or

```
this.map.animateToRegion({
       latitude: this.props.latitude,
       longitude: this.props.longitude,
       longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA ,
       latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA
}, 1)}
```

And you need to take add `ref={ref => { this.map = ref; } }` as follow so in funcation you get `this.map` as reference

```
         <MapView                   
                ref={ref => { this.map = ref; } }                 
                initialRegion={{
                  latitude: 37.78825,
                  longitude: -122.4324,
                  latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                  longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                }}
                 onRegionChangeComplete={(region) => { **somefuncation** } }            
          >
```